# Eclipse IDE for Android + Google app Engine shows strange error

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am watching this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7SxNNC429U) and doing exactly what the tutorial shows but after restarting Eclipse, even before running any application I'm seeing the following error:

```
Could not open the editor: Factory org.eclipse.jdt.ui.ClassFileEditorInputFactory returned null from createElement for editor id=org.eclipse.jdt.ui.ClassFileEditor name=ThreadPoolExecutor.class

at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.setVisibleEditor(EditorAreaHelper.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.setVisibleEditor(EditorManager.java:1429)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager$5.runWithException(EditorManager.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$31.runWithException(Workbench.java:1567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2548)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1384)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error? 
Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: was the environment working before? Did you try the normal stuff: restarting Eclipse, restarting the OS, etc...

Comment: recently had the same exception, cleaning the workspace was sufficient to solve this.